# Notification on Browser with Firebase

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM for mobile app. Now my project requires to deploy it into web-base application. But FCM just support Chrome-app only. Is there any solution for pushing notification from FCM to browser?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you're looking for Adding Push Notifications to a Web App, it's FCM too.

works with the Push API of HTML5 and uses ServiceWorkers

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/